# Laravel 5 Route for pagination search

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, routes

I'm trying to make a route for pagination results from a search.
My url when there is pagination is like this:

```
myproject/search?q=something/page/2
```

My routes are:

```html
Route::get('/search?q={search}/page/{page}/', ['uses' => 'SearchController@index','as' => 'search'])->where('page', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('/search',['uses' => 'SearchController@index','as' => 'search']);
```

It returns:

> NotFoundHttpException

How do I make my route for the pagination search results? Route for search is working.
In my controller I get a search string in this way:

```html
 $keyword=  Input::get('q');
```

Answer (score 2):

why dont you use laravels pagination, where you dont have to create route like that. The page number is taken as a get parameter so you dont have to worry about it. Or do it simply like this:

```
Route::get('/search/{search}/{page}', ['uses' => 'SearchController@index','as' => 'search']);
```

and in your search controller you'll get serchquery and page variable like this.

```
function index($searchQuery, $page){
        //code logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But url should look in this way: myproject/search?q=something/page/2  . Is it possible to make proper route for that?